# Do you know of any projects in PHP that use namespaces that I could study?

Tags: php, namespaces

I know namespaces are new in PHP but have been around for a long time in other languages.  I started out in PHP so I really have no experience using them, I have read many articles and post on here about namespace in PHP and I get thebasic idea of how to use it but it is still something that will probably take me a while for it to really sink in.  I learn better by seeing example code, so far I have not seen any opensource PHP projects that take use of the new namespace features of PHP.

My question, do you know of any projects in PHP that use namespace that I could look over?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both [Symfony 2](http://github.com/symfony/symfony/tree/master/src/Symfony/) and [Doctrine 2](http://trac.doctrine-project.org/browser/trunk) will be using namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

Check out any of the sections on this: http://flow3.typo3.org/documentation/manuals/flow3/

Answer (score 0):

The [Lithium framework](http://lithify.me/) is a PHP 5.3-oriented framework that makes extensive use of namespaces. The framework is still in development at this point but their use of namespaces and their loading class are excellent examples that you could look at.